# Is there a real photoshop competitor under Ubuntu?

Tags: photoshop

Is there a real Photoshop competitor under Ubuntu? GIMP unfortunately isn't. And it's also difficult to use a software that has a different GUI for me after so many years spent inside Photoshop.

Comment: If you had told us which feature is missing we may help you better.

Comment: Definitely layer effects. And croping is also hidden at a different place.

Comment: Gimp can be customized with a sheer uncountable number of plugins, some devoted to provide beloved Photoshop features (e.g. [Layer Effects](http://registry.gimp.org/node/186)). We should however not expect that all functions reside in the same place, have the same name, or provide an exactly identical behaviour as their counterparts in other softwares. When switching to Gimp we will have to invest some time to learn about differences. In case you have trouble in finding, using or installing such an add-on to Gimp don't hesitate to ask here but be as specific as possible.

Comment: Thanks, I have little time to learn a new workflow. The wheel has already been invented. Krita below is so far much more intuitive.

Comment: You're analogy is very simplistic. A graphics editor like Adobe Photoshop or GIMP is far from the the simplicity of so called "basic machines" like wheels. It's more like an intricate collection of thousands of wheels working together like a clockwork. Are you saying, we don't need new types of clocks, like one fitting on the bed stand, because we already have working wrist watches, that we can wear? Don't like the roman numerals on or the sound of the alarm of your clock? Well, you're out of luck, because there's only One True Way™ to make clocks – or so says Adobe.

Comment: At the back end a software uses even far more trivial things than a wheel. But what I'm saying is that Photoshop these days is intuitive in a way GIMP simply isn't.

Answer (score 4):

[Krita](https://krita.org/) is a creative sketching and painting application based on Calligra technology.

[image]

Krita is a KDE program for sketching and painting, offering an end–to–end solution for creating digital painting files from scratch by masters.

```
sudo apt-get install krita
```

But for a note, you can't find anything same as Photoshop. Every application has its soul and its way of handling, so you have to learn how to deal with each application and not have to do things as you used to do before.

And Still for me I consider Gimp is a great alternative and maybe powerful than Adobe Photoshop

Comment: Thank you, will try it. There are multiple entries of the same software in the ubuntu store.

Comment: you are welcome. Give it a  try

Comment: I installed it as you said and it works. But: I only receive a question mark icon. Any chances to change that?

Answer (score 2):

Yes ,you can run Photoshop for Windows using Wine , or work with alternative.

To install Wine type in console:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.7 winetricks
```

And install packages for photoshop(Wine):

```
winetricks atmlib gdiplus msxml3 msxml6 vcrun2005 vcrun2005sp1 vcrun2008 ie6 fontsmooth-rgb gecko
```

Or there are some alternatives:

1)[Pixrl online](http://apps.pixlr.com/editor/) in your browser.

2)Download  [Pixeluvo](http://www.pixeluvo.com/download/).

3)Download  [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/downloads/)

4)Get [GIMPshop](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimpshop.mirror/files/)

I recommend for you Gimp and Pixeluvo.

To install downloaded packages use this : [Installing software](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the same GUI the question really is "is Photoshop available for Linux"?  The question is better made to Adobe --- they are the ones who can decide to ship it or not.

I understand your problem (I too need some Windows-only software for my work too). So the options you have are:

- Pest Adobe to release a version for Linux;
- Use a quite powerful machine and use a virtual machine for photoshop (I use it for a photobook software I need);
- Try to see if things like [wine](http://www.wine-hq.org/) or [crossover](https://www.codeweavers.com/products/) can help;
- Get used to a different workflow (I am quite happy with [darktable](http://www.darktable.org/) + [gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) when needed)

Comment: Thanks, I think a good way would also if the GIMP devs would take a closer look at photoshop. People don't like to relearn patterns and psd is often a lot more intuitive (layer effects, croping, etc.)